# Inserting Button in customer account navigation - Sorting order

Tags: magento2, layout, extend

I inserted a button in customer/account navigation with the following file in my own module:

MyCompany/CustomRouter/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"
      label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current"
                   name="customer-account-navigation-pricelist-configure">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Download Pricelist (PDF)</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">configurepricelist</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

However, the button shows at the top of the list instead of the bottom. Is there any way I can make it show up at the bottom instead? (Or at least, below the core three links supplied by the customer module - among the other extensions.) I feel "Account Dashboard" really should be the top order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, you should use the `after` or `before` attribute, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd"
      label="Customer My Account (All Pages)" design_abstraction="custom">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current"
                   name="customer-account-navigation-pricelist-configure"
                   after="customer-account-navigation-account-edit-link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" 
                              translate="true">Download Pricelist (PDF)</argument>
                    <argument name="path" 
                              xsi:type="string">configurepricelist</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Note that if you have multiple that need to be sorted, they will all insert themselves directly after the element - so if the same name is used, they'll end up after that element in reverse order.